# Disappearing text in GUI prompt for Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently writing a small GUI in Linux for teaching younger member of my club how to do version control. I am using python Tkinter lib.

I have made a text space to insert text and have placed an example text there in the following way:

```
self.directory = tk.Text(self,height = 0)      
self.directory.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 10, padx = 2)    
self.directory = self.directory.insert(tk.END,"ex. /home/your_username/desktop")    
self.dirLabel = tk.Label(self,text = "Directory Path:")    
self.dirLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

I was wondering if there was any way so that when the cursor is placed on the box the text disappears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may answer your question, [How do I prepopulate a text field with suggested text in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447538/how-do-i-prepopulate-a-text-field-with-suggested-text-in-tkinter)

The relevant extract:

```
import Tkinter as tk

tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(height=10, width=10)
textbox.insert(tk.END, "Default")
textbox.pack()

# This is for demonstration purposes
tk.Text(height=10, width=10).pack()

def default(event):
    current = textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
    if current == "Default\n":
        textbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    elif current == "\n":
        textbox.insert("1.0", "Default")

textbox.bind("<FocusIn>", default)
textbox.bind("<FocusOut>", default)

tk.mainloop()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know, and I don't understand what you mean. Please ask a new question, using the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page and link back to this question (using the URL) if you think that your question is related.